# MailChimp RSS campaign: force include old posts

Tags: rss, mailchimp

I'm using MailChimp for an RSS campaign but it seems MailChimp only includes new posts from the rss feed. In my case MailChimp should include old posts to. 
I thought that tampering with the post's pubDate (setting it to now) in the feed would make MailChimp think it was new but that doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have an idea on how to 'fool' MailChimp so it includes old posts to?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After chatting with Mailchimp support it seems it should be the RSS `<pubDate>` that defines if your post is included or not.
Problem was that my timezone setting in Mailchimp was not the same as the time timezone posted in the RSS feed...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the FEEDBLOCK tags (https://us12.admin.mailchimp.com/). MailChimp told me "Any FEEDBLOCK tag in a sense will be its own feed so any dates set for the RSS campaign are ignored."